# Build and Deploy Multiple Docker images to kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have an application such as below structure which multiple services has their own Dockerfile.ı would like to deploy my application via Jenkins using Helm to kubernetes but I can not decide what is the best way to handle this?

Should I try to use multi-stage builds if yes how can I handle this?
Should I create two helm charts for each of them or any way to handle this with one helm chart?

```
└── app-images-dashboard
    ├── Readme.md
    ├── cors-proxy
    │   ├── Dockerfile
    │   ├── lib
    │   │   ├── cors-anywhere.js
    │   │   ├── help.txt
    │   │   ├── rate-limit.js
    │   │   └── regexp-top-level-domain.js
    │   ├── package.json
    │   └── server.js
    └── app-images-dashboard
        ├── Dockerfile
        ├── components
        │   └── image_item.js
        ├── images
        │   └── beta.png
        ├── index.html
        ├── main.js
        └── stylesheets
            └── style.css
```

Comment: @lindhe, thanks for your kind response.Maybe it is my fault to not explain my confusion clearly. Frankly ı had a chance to deploy several applications via helm and kubernetes but each project only one docker file and not multi-stage. That is why it confuse me what is the best practices if project has two dockerfile?

Comment: Doing a multi-stage Dockerfile is best-practice, but only for pretty complex setups. If having a single build stage works fine, then go with that. :) Helm is a tool to help you deploy (run) containers in Kubernetes, and you can have everything in a single container or many containers that do different tasks.

Comment: @lindhe, yeah but i do not want multi container in one pod.I want to create twop seperate pod  for each dockerfile..Is there any way to handle this in helm? Cause i could not able to find any examples that specify mutiple container in deployment.yaml with two container under below spec.

Comment: Ah, I think I get your problem now. A deployment describes a set of identical pods (i.e. one or more pods), but if you want multiple pods you should have multiple deployment.yaml. Like `cors-proxy-deployment.yaml` and `dashboard.yaml`.

Comment: Can subchart cover this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A helm chart represent a whole application. You have 1 application with 2 slices. So you need only 1 helm chart.

Comment: So how can i create two separate pods for each container? In this case one pod has two container which i do not prefer

Comment: semural answered you. I guess only way to handle this create two different deployment.yaml in templates for each service using one helm chart